# Retrieving data from SQL Server and turning it into a json format?

Tags: php, sql-server, json, angularjs, windows

I am using PHP 5.6.0 and connected to my local SQL Server. I was able to retrieve the data, but it is in an array format. I would like to convert it into a json format.

**What I get:**

```
(     
    [date] => 2013-02-05 16:02:02.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/New_York
)
```

**What I want:**

```
(
    "date" : "2013-02-05 16:02:02.000000",
    "timezone_type" : "3",
    "timezone" : "America/New_York"
)
```

**Here is my code:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

$result = array(); 

do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $result[] = print_r($row); 
    }
} while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt));


echo json_encode($result);


sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

My understanding is that json_encode should convert my data but it doesn't seem to work that way.

Thank you!

Comment: why are you using `print_r($row)`? Is that just a typo with some debugging? If not try it without the print_r

Comment: @Styphon I am using print_r because it's the only way I can actually see the code. without it, I get a blank screen.

Comment: Then you should use `print_r($row); $result[] = $row;`. What you currently have is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there were two mistakes in your code. First one is

```
$result[] = print_r($row);
```

You are executing a function and pushing values in array at same time. You should push value in array here. Like

```
$result[] = $row;
```

And Second one is, not printing the JSON varibale after encoding it. So your code would be

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

$result = array(); 

do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
       $result[] = $row; 
    }
} while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt));


sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn); //Close the connnectiokn first

echo json_encode($result); //You will get the encoded array variable
```

Comment: Thank you for submitting @Vineet but this  still didn't help for some reason. I got a blank screen.

Comment: call `die()` or `exit()` at the end of the your script.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is quite unsual try it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

$result = array(); 

while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($stmt))
{
 array_push($result, $row);
} 

echo json_enconde($result);


sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

Comment: Thank for this code but I am using SQL Server so I can't use mssql_fetch_array()

Comment: Yes you can! **mssql_fetch_array is not mysql_fetch_array** as seen here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-array.php

Comment: I can't suggest an edit, but for anyone copying and pasting this, there's a typo in the line that starts with echo. It should be `json_encode` not `json_enconde`

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server 2016 has FOR JSON clause that automatically transforms result set to JSON see [Format Query Results as JSON with FOR JSON (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921882.aspx)